# Rails fields_forのN+1問題・エラー表示

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現状以下の問題を認識しています。

#### 登場モデル

以下の様なモデル例で説明します。

Account has_many posts
Post belongs_to category
Category

- `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts`でAccountのedit時にpostを複数編集

#### `<%= f.fields_for :posts do |f| %>`の場合

上記のfileds_for内に、`f.object.category.try(:name)`などのように記述するとN+1問題が発生します。

#### `<%= f.fields_for :posts, f.object.posts.includes(:category) do |f| %>`の場合

N+1問題は解決しますが、Postモデルに`validates :title, presence: true`としていた場合に、`f.object.posts.includes(:category)`を指定しているとpostsが再読み込みされてしまいエラー情報が消えてしまう。

---

上記のN+1問題を解決しつつ、postsモデルのerrors情報を保持するにはどのように記述すればよいのでしょうか？

コード例は以下のリンクにあります。

https://github.com/kntmrkm-public/fields-for-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` を使って、関連するデータを事前にロードすれば良いと思います。

app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:

```
def set_account
  @account = Account.includes(:posts => :category).find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: 上記のコードで意図したとおり動きました。ありがとうございます！